# Azure DevOps 2020 - how do I select which artifacts to download for a release pipline (18.170.30525.1 (Azure DevOps Server 2020))

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-devops-server-2020

I have a build pipeline with 2 publish artifacts.
[image]

In my release pipeline i want to download just the first artifact.
I know that it should be possible as I have read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/artifacts?view=azure-devops)

> In Azure Pipelines, you can, however, select which artifacts you want to download to the agent for a specific job and stage of the deployment. Typically, you will do this to improve the efficiency of the deployment pipeline when the tasks in that job do not require all or any of the artifacts, or if you implement custom code in a task to download the artifacts you require.

but I cant find it...

This is how the release job details look like:
[image]

as you can see the artifact selection is missing.

here is how I configured the artifact in the release pipe:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently there is an issue with on premiss none NTLM agents.
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/520932/azure-devops-server-2019-where-is-partially-downlo.html

> Partial artifacts feature isn't enabled by default in Azure DevOps Server 2019. We have an issue with "Download Build artifacts" not working with NTLM based proxy hence we couldn't roll out this feature to OnPremise customers.

Comment: I reported a documentation bug: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/9618